# Are there alternatives to create a merchant profile on Google Play when your country is not listed?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, android-layout, google-play

I have been developing for an android app for a very long time and when I tried to publish the app and set the price, I was surprised that my country was not listed in the countries allowed to create a merchant profile, I am now asking are there any alternatives to this situation other than having someone else create the profile for you, can I use paypal or payoneer for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use vpn and this way Google will recognize you as if you are in another country

example
https://windscribe.net/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).